# How to create Visual Studio solution and project files from NANT build file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nant, csproj

I have a C# project built using NANT. Is there a convenient way to generate VS solution and project files to open and compile this project using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Shameless plug: [generate-msbuild](https://github.com/skolima/generate-msbuild) task on GitHub. It doesn't do a full faithful conversion, but it does create a Visual Studio solution that you can open in IDE and compile from there. Also, might give you a nice starting point if you think about migrating your build from NAnt to MSBuild. If you have any problems (or bugs), please ask on the GitHub page. That was tested on a couple large projects, including CruiseControl.NET, NAnt and Boo, so should handle most scenarios.

Also, new MSBuild (starting with .NET 4.0) can do everything NAnt can - most users just don't realise it.

Answer (score 0):

No, nant (while-complete) allows to much flexibility in building that you could represent in VS solution and projects (Fixed List of Files).  Maybe you could create a way of generating solution and project files from nant build files for a specific subset of build scripts or record how the C# is assembled but I would not consider that convenient, at least for small to medium sized solutions.

Fortunately if sufficient recent versions of VS I find it quite convenient and easy to import files into new solutions and projects.